# STM32F107 generate PPM signal

Tags: arm, timer

I need generate special signal PPM for my rc toys, for example:
[image]

I'll use stm32F107 and I would use a timer which will be a resolution of 0.1us. The web is a lot of examples to generate the PWM signal but I can not find anything on the PPM.

Present someone an example?

Comment: I take it that you can't code anything low level, at all, and that you have to use libraries others wrote. So you are really just asking if someone knows just the right already-written library/program to conveniently use with your device and with whatever you have as your RC toys? (The above diagram looks to me almost good enough to go write code, already.) Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Both PPM and PWM do 'something' at some time, the only difference is whether the something is go up, go down, or don't change, so very low level code, data even. Handling the counters, turnover interrupts, is the same for both.

Comment: Mbed supports a lot of stm32 micro-controllers. Programming is very easy if you select a supported micro. See if anything suits your needs - https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/?tvend=10

Comment: The link that I posted is for evaluation boards, but you can use the same code on your custom made board as well.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I used this fragment of code: http://www.keil.com/download/docs/354.asp